# Using mysql in React nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typeerror

I am trying to switch a webpage from php into NodeJS React. So far things have gone well, but it also means I need a database connection to my mySql DB.

The thing is I've tried the guide at https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#install for node-mysql, and though them seem to be pretty straight forward examples, none of them works. The same goes for the examples used on this page.

Using the following ( Node v5.4.0 ) :
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "node-mysql": "^0.4.2",
    "react": "^0.14.6",

I am trying to get a real error of the code. Knowing I get a connection is easier to fix. But unfortunatly I don't even seem to get that far. The example from the guides usually use this : ( updated to reflect last code )

```
var React   = require ('react')
var mysql   = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'jay',
  password : 'jay',
  degug    : 'true',
});

connection.connect(function(err) { if ( !err ) { 
    console.log("Connected to MySQL"); 
    } else { console.log("Error : ",err) }
});
```

Where as the require ('react') is of my own contruction. As far as I understand this should give me a "DB not found", or a "Connection failed" or whatever, but I only get the message **"Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function"** in the console.

I've asked console.log(connection) and I do get an object so I know connection is set. I've also looked at the mysql object dervived from require('mysql') and it does give an object containing something called "createConnection: function createConnection(config)" which as far as I am concerned is the function that I'm getting an error about not existing.

Or am I missing something here ? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try connection.connect(function(err) {
  if ( !err ) {
    console.log("Connected to MySQL");
  } else if ( err ) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

Comment: Just tried. Thanks for the advice, but unfortunatly to no avail. Same error in console log.

Comment: Use 'debug: true' option in createConnection and add the output above.

Comment: Updated the code part with currently tried code. Still no luck tough. Still hitting the "Net.createConnection is not a function", also exchanged your else if, with a simple else. Neighter of them is hit tough, so the connection.connect doesn't even seem to give an error. It's just simply not run.

Comment: Are you running mysql server? If yes, how?

Comment: No. The intention is to connect to an external server. I'd just like to get a mysql error code first,  knowing that it atleast tries to connect. So localhost is simply a test,  trying to get connection failed or some other than 'is not a function '

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for. Since I want to translate my old php into javascript node it will fail due to browserify it would seem. And since my current website provider doesn't support standalone nodejs I guess I'll need to implement php with javascript to make it work.

Thanks for the inputs tough @Tushar